# How to animate a contour plot produced by a bilinear interpolation?

Tags: python, animation, plot, contour

I would like to visualize the magnitude of VM with respect to time t. In the following program, t is set to zero. I would appreciate it if one could tell me how to produce an animation of the bilinear interpolation contour plot. Thank you!
Please here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos, sin, pi, exp, sqrt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

nx=30
ny=30

nu=0.0025
p=2*pi

x = np.linspace(0,p,nx)
y = np.linspace(0,p,ny)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_xlim(0,p)
ax.set_ylim(0,p)

t=0
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
U=-cos(X)*sin(Y)*exp(-2*nu*t)
V=sin(X)*cos(Y)*exp(-2*nu*t)
VM=sqrt(U**2+V**2)

im = plt.imshow(VM, interpolation='bilinear', origin='lower',
            cmap=cm.gray, extent=(0, p, 0, p))
levels = np.arange(-1.2, 1.6, 0.2)

# add a vertical colorbar.
CBI = plt.colorbar(im, orientation='vertical', shrink=0.8)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mostly copied from [here](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/). See there for in depth explanations.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos, sin, pi, exp, sqrt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib import animation

nx=30
ny=30

nu=0.0025
p=2*pi

x = np.linspace(0,p,nx)
y = np.linspace(0,p,ny)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_xlim(0,p)
ax.set_ylim(0,p)

t=0
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
U=-cos(X)*sin(Y)*exp(-2*nu*t)
V=sin(X)*cos(Y)*exp(-2*nu*t)
VM=sqrt(U**2+V**2)

im = plt.imshow(VM, interpolation='bilinear', origin='lower',
            cmap=cm.gray, extent=(0, p, 0, p))
levels = np.arange(-1.2, 1.6, 0.2)

# add a vertical colorbar.
CBI = plt.colorbar(im, orientation='vertical', shrink=0.8)


def init():
    im.set_data((np.empty_like(VM)))
    return im,

def animate(t):
    U=-cos(X)*sin(Y)*exp(-2*nu*t)
    V=sin(X)*cos(Y)*exp(-2*nu*t)
    VM=sqrt(U**2+V**2)
    im.set_data(VM)
    return im,

# # call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your powerful answer! That's fantastic!  :)

Comment: just have another question! Do you know how to obtain a colored bar with different colors (instead of just the grey color). Thank you!

Comment: change `cmap=cm.gray` into another colormap. [list of colormaps](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps)